# Pyspark - Is it possible to write a pyspark dataframe to a custom log table in Log Analytics workspace

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-synapse, azure-log-analytics

I have a pyspark dataframe that contains information about the tables that I have on sql database (creation date, number of rows, etc)

Sample data:

```
 {
   "Day":"2023-04-28",
   "Environment":"dev",
   "DatabaseName":"default",
   "TableName":"discount",
   "CountRows":31253
}
```

and I want to write this dataframe to a custom log table that I created on Log Analytics workspace, is it possible?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use below code to write data into custom log table.

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import datetime


def build_signature(customer_id, shared_key, date, content_length, method, content_type, resource):
    x_headers = 'x-ms-date:' + date
    string_to_hash = '\n'.join([method, str(content_length), content_type, x_headers, resource])
    bytes_to_hash = bytes(string_to_hash, encoding='utf-8')
    key_bytes = base64.b64decode(shared_key)
    decoded_hash = hmac.new(key_bytes, bytes_to_hash, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    encoded_hash = base64.b64encode(decoded_hash).decode('utf-8')
    authorization = f'SharedKey {customer_id}:{encoded_hash}'
    return authorization

def post_log_analytics_data(customer_id, shared_key, body, log_type):
    method = 'POST'
    content_type = 'application/json'
    resource = '/api/logs'
    rfc1123date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
    content_length = len(body)
    
    signature = build_signature(
                    customer_id=customer_id,
                    shared_key=shared_key,
                    date=rfc1123date,
                    content_length=content_length,
                    method=method,
                    content_type=content_type,
                    resource=resource)
                    
    uri = f'https://{customer_id}.ods.opinsights.azure.com{resource}?api-version=2016-04-01'
    headers = {
    'Authorization': signature,
    'Log-Type': log_type,
    'x-ms-date': rfc1123date,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.post(uri, headers=headers, data=body)
    return response.status_code

json_data = <your dataframe>.toJSON().collect()[0]
status_code = post_log_analytics_data(<your workspace id>, <your primary key>, json_data, <log_type>)
print(status_code)
```

And the results are below,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @JayashankarGS, I think you saved my life :). Just one question before put this answer as a solution. I ran the code and the status it was 200, it was successful. But is not appearing any data on CL table. Did you do any kind of configuration before? For example did you create the CL table via DCR-based or MMA? I created for MMA. And I have to wait a while to see the data or it will appear immediately? Once again super thanks !!!

Comment: `post_log_analytics_data(<your workspace id>, <your primary key>, json_data, <log_type>)` In this function i gave the **log_type** as **Dataframe_log**. This will create a table in logs as highlighted in first image and,  in second image you observe i ran a query by pasting **Dataframe_log_CL** in query tab and i got the details below.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try to figure out, because is only appearing one row and I have more rows on that dataframe. I changed this part ->[eval(i) for i in df_tables_cr.toJSON().collect()] to get more rows in json, but I got an error: too many values to unpack (expected 2). So, I'll try to see

Comment: yeah. I have given single row to show simple example

Comment: super thanks again, I already created a solution to write more than one row